# catch(...) not catching exceptions in gcc 9.2.0 coverage build

Tags: c++, c, exception, gcc, code-coverage

I'm developing a function foo() to be called from a huge application written in C. The foo() function calls routines from a C++ library. I have declared foo() as an extern "C" function. The implementation of foo() looks like this:

```
void* foo() 
{
    try
    {
        // Call routines from the C++ library
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        // Do cleanup and return nullptr;
    }
}
```

This approach worked fine, until I started using a coverage build of the entire application, built using the --coverage option of gcc. When running foo() under the coverage build, exceptions from the C++ library are not caught. The coverage tests for foo() are terminating with a message that looks like this:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of <name of the exception object>
...
Abort(coredump)
```

I have verified that the control enters the try{} block but never enters the catch {} block when the exception occurs. This behavior occurs only in the coverage build. The issue doesn't occur in the debug or optimized builds.

The main thing that's different about the coverage build is that it's done with gcc 9.2.0. The other builds are done with Intel compiler and gcc 7.4.0 compatibility. I have to use gcc 9.2.0 for coverage build because that's what the rest of the (huge) application uses for coverage.

I have experimented by using many different flags (e.g., -fexceptions, static linking with libstdcpp, etc.) in gcc 9.2.0 with no success.

Does anyone know of possible reasons why a catch(...) statement like this won't catch exceptions? One of my suspects was that I was initially using an Intel + gcc 7.4.0 optimized build of the C++ library (because I don't need to see the coverage for the C++ library) and linking it against the gcc 9.2.0 coverage build of foo(). But I recompiled the C++ library also using gcc 9.2.0, and the problem persists.

Any compiler options I may have missed and should try?

Thanks.

Comment: As long as we did not know how you compile your application, there is no chance to get the underlying reason. I expect you compiled with fnoexeption

Comment: @Klaus, Thanks for commenting. I have made sure that the "fnoexception" flag is NOT used in the application compilation.

Comment: I did not find a version specific bug report. As this I expect the problem is on your side. And we still have o idea what you are really doing. Maybe a full clean and recompile?